# How to stop the runnable thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I am using this code the start the thread.

How can I stop this thread

```
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                            }
        }).start();
```

Comment: It will stop immediately because the run-method does nothing.

Comment: I have some code in run method. After completing  the execution of run method does the thread stop??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to note here:

1. As stated above, this code does nothing. The thread starts and then immediately stops because there is nothing to run.
2. After the thread completes the `run()` method, it auto closes. The only way to have a thread keep going is to keep it in a loop. The only way to then stop the thread is to exit the loop. There isn't a `System.exit()` equivalent for a thread.
3. I don't think you need to have a new runnable, since the class `Thread` has its own `run` method which would just call the runnable's run method anyways.

Answer (score 1):

The thread will automatically stop after the runnable has finished executing. There is no need to stop it manually unless you have a loop that requires ending within it.